# Seek issue of HEVC streams with ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, hevc

I'm attempting to perform a seek operation in an MPEG-TS stream that contains a HEVC encoded bit stream. The HEVC stream is encoded using the following command;

```
ffmpeg -s:v 1920x1080 -i kimono.yuv -c:v libx265 -x265-params crf=23:fps=30:keyint=10:min-keyint=10 -c:a copy -f mpegts testhevc.ts
```

The seek operation is attempted with ffplay as;

```
ffplay testhevc.ts -ss 5 -vf showinfo
```

The information shown gives multiple initial errors with missing POCs, such as;

> Could not find ref with POC 126

However, everything works fine when the same operation is performed with H.264. The encoding with H.264/AVC is performed as;

```
ffmpeg -s:v 1920x1080 -i kimono.yuv -c:v libx265 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -r 30 -keyint_min 10 -g 10 -c:a copy -f mpegts testh264.ts
```

Is this an issue with the ffmpeg tools for HEVC or am I missing something in these commands?.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a similar error encoding a HEVC stream in .mp4, did you found any solutions?